# Possible to send multiple data to selector with CCCallFuncND without creating a new class?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, action

In cocos2d the action `CCCallFunND` allows you to call a selector and send it data, but the selector I want to call takes both an `NSString` and a `float.`  Can you send more than one datum and if so, what is the syntax.

I know I can make a new object class that contains both types and pass that, but that seems kludgy to me.  The whole idea of the method I'm calling is to cut down the overhead, and doing it with a new class seems like it defeats the purpose.

Here's the syntax...

```
CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:(id) selector:(SEL) data:(void *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution will be to create a structure with your string and float. But you can also create a NSArray and put your NSString and NSNumber to it. Then just pass the array.